# Void in a constructor

Tags: java

Java 14.

```
class InitByConstructionVoid{
    String aux;

    public void InitByConstructionVoid(){
        this.aux = "aux";
    }

}


class InitByConstruction{
    String aux;

    InitByConstruction(){
        this.aux = "aux";
    }

}


public class Ex2 {
    private String str;

    public static void main(String [] args){

        InitByConstruction con = new InitByConstruction();
        System.out.println("InitByConstruction: " + con.aux);

        InitByConstructionVoid conVoid = new InitByConstructionVoid();
        System.out.println("InitByConstructionVoid: " + conVoid.aux);

    }
}
```

**Result:**

```
InitByConstruction: aux
InitByConstructionVoid: null
```

Could you help me understand what is the meaning of that word void here? I mean why it influenced like that.

Comment: That's not a constructor, that is a method with the same name as the class. Method names should be written in camelCase, according to the Java Naming Conventions. Such a method is technically not forbidden, but it leads only to confusion.

Comment: `public void InitByConstructionVoid() {...}` is an *instance method* which is just not called; when `InitByConstruction() {...}` is a *constructor* which is called when instance is created by `new`

Comment: Looks that you are right. Why such a subtle nuance is left in a language called safe?

Comment: That's not a nuance. That's a terrible practice which should be avoided.

Comment: ok. Why such a terrible practice is not forbidden by the compiler? It didn't even show a warning.

Comment: Because there are no good enough reasons for completely forbidding such constructs.

Comment: It is not a bug because you can't use methods and constructors instead of each other. in compilers this kind of code comes with a warning but it still can be compiled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`void` is a type. By adding it to the signature of `InitByConstructionVoid`, you've degraded the constructor to a normal instance method.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a constructor, it is a method with the same name.
and when you use this:

```
InitByConstructionVoid conVoid = new InitByConstructionVoid();
```

in fact, you are calling the default constructor which is not implemented by you. so the body is empty and the field "aux" is not set in that.

to make it more clear, try to write that with an input and you will see that your code does not compile.

Answer (score 0):

The keyword "void" in any programming language usually means that the function will not have a return type, so please erase the void syntax if you are looking to get a value for aux in the scope of your InitByConstructionVoid() function.

Answer (score -1):

```
InitByConstruction(){
        this.aux = "aux";
    }
```

This should be public for it to be acessible outside the class.Hence the null problem.

Comment: No. You are wrong. And the example definitely shows that. And the question was more about InitByConstructionVoid.